# How to aggregate number of occure each value per column in table in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, aggregate, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
COL1 | COL2  | COL3
-----|-------|------
111  | A     | C
111  | B     | C
222  | A     | D
333  | A     | D
```

And I need to aggregate abve table to know how many each value in columns occured, so as to have something like below:

```
COL2_A  | COL2_B | COL3_C | COL3_D
--------|--------|--------|--------
3       | 1      | 2      | 2
```

Because:

- COL_2A = 3, because in COL2 value "A" exists 3 times
  and so on...

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide or in PROC SQL ?

I need the output as SAS dataset

Comment: Do you need this iin a report or a new SAS data set?

Comment: I nedd this as new SAS dataset :)

Comment: What kind of further analysis are you doing with this transposed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input COL1 COL2 $ COL3 $;
datalines;
111 A C 
111 B C 
222 A D 
333 A D 
;

data long;
   set have;
   array col COL2 COL3;
   do over col;
      c = col;
      n  = cats(vname(col), '_', c);
      output;
   end;
run;

proc summary data = long nway;
   class n;
   output out = freq(drop = _TYPE_);
run;

proc transpose data = freq out = wide_freq(drop = _:);
   id n;
run;
```

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you PeterClemmensen, I gave best answer! :)